# Xamarin Google Pay implementation 2022

Tags: xamarin, wallet

how to implement google pay in xamarin ? Im using Google Tap and pay SDK (gms:play-services-tapandpay:18.2.0) followed this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar

**but not all methods were created**

Comment: You can try to use the `Xamarin.GoogleServices.Wallet` package to implement the google pay in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this github issue, there is an explanation for unsuccessful binding of play-services-tapandpay:

https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/196

> Unfortunately we cannot provide the SDK as it is a private SDK. If
> you have customers asking you to build bindings, you should be able to work with your customers to get access to the SDK through them.